# Hypernym for buildings, fossils, spiders and particles

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

Edited in response to answers/comments.

I'm trying to find a term (other than 'objects' or 'things') which I can use to describe the commonality of substance which all the things that have been named after Nelson Mandela - which include inanimate objects such as buildings, 3.5-million-year-old species of woodpeckers, a species of spider discovered in 2002, and a nuclear particle - share in common.

Suggestions which touch on their common attribute of being named after Mandela are useful, but not what I'm after.

The word could be used in a context such as 'Many xxxxxs are named after NM' or 'NM had many xxxxxs named after him.'

Any ideas?

Comment: "Nelson-Mandela-named-objects"? "Mandeliana"? Why do you need a _single_ word for 'things named after Mandela'?

Comment: I'm going to go with "things" here. Technically not everyone would consider a species of woodpecker to be an object (as opposed to an individual bird of that species).

Comment: Maybe *Mandelanyms*?

Comment: Are you looking for a term specifically for Mandela, or for a generic term for a collection of namesakes?

Comment: Leon, are you asking about Mandela in particular or for how to call things in general that are named after a particular person, or about the name of the thing that includes all those items, it just being coincidence that they are named after Mandela?

Comment: @bib Great suggestion!

Comment: @Mitch thanks for the question. I've reworded to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for making me Google for "Mandela particle". Very sad to learn that it turned out to be just an artefact of experimental error.

Comment: What would you call a collection of such things, a *Mandelorium?*

Comment: Even though it doesn't strictly answer the question, it's a great word.

Comment: "Many Mandeloriums are named after Mandela"? That doesn't sound right for what you are describing. "Many things..." does sound right. Are you looking for an eponym or a hypernym?

Comment: Though you've accepted an answer, it is still unclear what you're looking for. Are you looking for things named after Mandela ('Mandelaiana'), things named after a person ('eponymous class'), the word for words for things named after a person ('eponym'), the word for general terms encompassing specific terms ('hypernym'), a word for the specific class including those items you mention, which only coincidentally happen to be named after Mandela (''object', 'things') or something else?

Comment: @Mitch - I gave up on finding a common hypernymous term for the 'things', and accepted the blanket term which covered both bases - eponymous and hypernymous (the latter by implication).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that a collection of oddities is an *odditorium*, a collection of dolphins is a *dolphinarium*, a collection of ants a *formicarium*, a collection of doves a *columbarium*, a collection of the four Gospels an *evangelistarium*, and a collection of myths and legends a *legendarium*, then it seems like you could make a passably convincing argument that the collection “of all things Mandelian” would in turn be a ***Mandelorium***.

Answer (score 6):

[Namesakes](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/namesake): someone or something that has the same name as another person or thing.

Probably from name's sake; first Known Use: 1646.

Linnaeus (the father of modern taxonomy) was so taken by the twinflower that he named it *Linnaea borealis* (and is depicted holding it in a portrait); it was his namesake. In turn, the name Linnaea became *its* namesake.

Comment: They are, indeed, all namesakes, but this describes the attribute they all share, rather than the word I'm looking for, which would ideally be a blanket term like 'things' or 'objects', which describes their common substance.

Answer (score 5):

**"Eponym"**, as used in [definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eponym) #2:

> 1:  one for whom or which something is or is believed to be named
>
> 2:  a name (as of a drug or a disease) based on or derived from an
>   eponym
>
> — ep·onym·ic  adjective
>
> Examples of EPONYM
>
> Joseph Banks was surely the eponym of eponyms. From Alaska to
>   Indonesia, from Tierra del Fuego to Tasmania, there are capes,
>   islands, straits, mountains, bays, points, channels, peninsulas,
>   counties and towns named after him. —Pat Rogers, Times Literary
>   Supplement, 3–9 June 1988
>
> Origin of EPONYM
>
> Greek epōnymos, from epōnymos eponymous, from epi- + onyma name — more
>   at name First Known Use: 1846

Comment: - thanks, but the word I'm looking for is a synonym for 'things' or 'objects' which would cover all the classes mentioned in my question.

Comment: Then this becomes a logic problem.  If you take away the only common denominator for your list of disparate objects, which is Mandela's name, there is no word to tie the list together.  If Mandela's name is not a factor in the name of this group of objects, you may consider rewording your question.

Comment: Exactly, Kristina. I have. We talk about physical objects, metaphysical objects, animate objects and inanimate objects, but when it comes to streets, nuclear particles, and extinct species, 'objects' seems somewhat inadequate.